# Can someone review this vb.net code and tell me what's wrong with it?

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k ""Kiddion's Modest Menu\modest-menu.exe")
```

What I'm trying to do is open my launcher from my desktop, open cmd and have my code tell it to open a folder (Kiddion's Modest Menu) and then open an exe (modest-menu.exe).
Whenever I try to run it cmd gives an error saying

> Kiddion's is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

When I try to type "Kiddion's Modest Menu\modest-menu.exe it launches the program. If I type the code with the quote in front it gives the same error. Is it not putting a quotation mark before "Kiddion's"? If somebody could help me fix this that would be great :)

Comment: At the very least you need a quote at the end of the file path too, i.e. `Process.Start("cmd", "/k ""Kiddion's Modest Menu\modest-menu.exe""")`. That code is going to assume that the specified folder is under the current working directory for your app. Is it? If it's not then you need to either change the current directory before executing that code or else specify the full path in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way instead:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k " & Chr(34) & "Kiddion's Modest Menu\modest-menu.exe" & Chr(34))
```

Comment: Tried it but to no avail, it just opened up cmd and did nothing. I think I'll just have users select the file location and the program just uses that.